# What is the advantage of using Euler Angles over spherical coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, euler-angles, geometry-class-library

I'm working with an application where relative coordinate systems are stored as a list of Euler Angles and a translation.

Is there any good reason, to represent the rotation using Euler angles over spherical coordinates?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: You would have to tell us how the angles are being generated and used, and I suspect this question would be a better fit on [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) or maybe the Maths site.